# My Javascript does not execute, does anyone know why?

Tags: javascript

could you please help me with this code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome to Daily News</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts.js">
</script>
<link href="homepage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="body">
<div class="header">
<a href="#" title="Home"><img id="header-image" src="news_logo.png" /></a>

<form id="login-form" action="customerLogin.html" method="post" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td><label for="loginid">Login:</label></td>
     <td id="login-form"><input id="login-boxes" type="text" id="loginid"></td>

      <td><label for="pword">Password:</label></td>
      <td id="login-form"><input id="login-boxes" type="password" id="pword"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td id="login-buttons"><input type="submit" value=" Sign In ">
       <input type="reset" value="Clear form">
       </td>
    </tr>

   </table>
  </form>

</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Javascript is:

```
function validate(loginForm)
{
 var booValid = true;
 var strErrorMessage = "";
 var minLength=5;
 var maxLength=10;

 if(loginForm.pword.value.length < minLength)
 {
  strErrorMessage = "password must at least 5 characters\n";
  booValid=false;
 }

 if(loginForm.pword.value.length > maxLength)
 {
  strErrorMessage = "pasword must not more than 10 characters\n";
  booValid=false;
 }


  if(loginForm.loginid.value.indexOf("@") == -1)
 {
  strErrorMessage = "please enter an e-mail address as your login name\n";
  booValid=false;
 }

 if(!booValid)
 {
  alert(strErrorMessage);
 }

 return booValid;
}
```

I couldn't figure out what was with this code, it doesn't seem to read from javascript at all.

I have no idea why it does not. I've also tried to use only Login Form and javascript then it works and when i put everything together then it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes i think so but i can't change since i have already ticked on User455892.

Comment: I don't mind and I know Armando, he prob doesn't care either. You should be able to uncheck, though. The important thing to remember is learning when to use ‘name‘, ‘class‘, and ‘id‘

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You probably want to replace every `id=` with `class=`
2. Instead of your later `id`s you want to use `name`

   ```
   <input id="login-boxes" type="text" id="loginid">
   <input id="login-boxes" type="password" id="pword">
   ```

   to

   ```
   <input class="login-boxes" type="text"     name="loginid">
   <input class="login-boxes" type="password" name="pword">
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change :

> `<input id="login-boxes" type="password" id="pword">`

to
`<input id="login-boxes" type="password" name="pword">`

and

> `<input id="login-boxes" type="password" id="pword">`

to

```
<input id="login-boxes" type="password" name="pword">
```